# Sbt commands stopped working when I run them for Java 11

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt, java-11

I've got a very strange issue when one of the Play framework projects I'm working on was upgraded to Java 11. All sbt commands just stopped working and freeze when I run them with Java 11. For example I have this bat file to run my application:

```
set PATH=G:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\bin;%PATH%
set JAVA_HOME=G:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot
sbt -jvm-debug 9997 "run 9002"
```

Sbt command can be other (e.g. compile, just "sbt" and so on). When I change paths in bat file to Java 8 folder sbt works. When paths are pointing to Java 11 - it freezes. Also in Idea refresh sbt freezes as well when Java 11 is selected for the project. Any advices would be appreciated (at least how to debug this issue). Sbt version is 1.3.6
Jstack log:

```
2020-04-14 21:37:09
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.6+10 mixed mode):

Threads class SMR info:
_java_thread_list=0x000000005e363070, length=11, elements={
0x00000000002d9000, 0x0000000018331000, 0x000000001833d800, 0x000000001834e000,
0x000000001834f000, 0x0000000018354000, 0x000000001835b000, 0x000000001835d800,
0x0000000018506000, 0x000000001850c800, 0x00000000626ea800
}

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=3073.22ms elapsed=700.57s tid=0x00000000002d9000 nid=0x323c runnable  [0x00000000020cb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.6/FileInputStream.java:279)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(java.base@11.0.6/BufferedInputStream.java:290)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(java.base@11.0.6/BufferedInputStream.java:351)
    - locked <0x00000000fcf54920> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(java.base@11.0.6/StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(java.base@11.0.6/StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(java.base@11.0.6/StreamDecoder.java:178)
    - locked <0x00000000fcf56b98> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(java.base@11.0.6/InputStreamReader.java:185)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(java.base@11.0.6/BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@11.0.6/BufferedReader.java:326)
    - locked <0x00000000fcf56b98> (a java.io.InputStreamReader)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(java.base@11.0.6/BufferedReader.java:392)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.io.github.soc.directories.Util.runCommands(Util.java:160)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.io.github.soc.directories.Util.getWinDirs(Util.java:122)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.io.github.soc.directories.ProjectDirectories.fromPath(ProjectDirectories.java:221)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.shaded.io.github.soc.directories.ProjectDirectories.from(ProjectDirectories.java:274)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.paths.CoursierPaths.coursierDirectories(CoursierPaths.java:82)
    - locked <0x00000000fcf1f6d8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.paths.CoursierPaths.computeCacheDirectory(CoursierPaths.java:44)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.paths.CoursierPaths.cacheDirectory(CoursierPaths.java:70)
    - locked <0x00000000fcf1f6e8> (a java.lang.Object)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.paths.CachePath.defaultCacheDirectory(CachePath.java:93)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheDefaults$.location$lzycompute(CacheDefaults.scala:16)
    - locked <0x00000000fd0ebd70> (a lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheDefaults$)
    at lmcoursier.internal.shaded.coursier.cache.CacheDefaults$.location(CacheDefaults.scala:16)
    at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution$.defaultCacheLocation(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:262)
    at sbt.coursierint.LMCoursier$.defaultCacheLocation(LMCoursier.scala:43)
    at sbt.Defaults$.globalIvyCore$lzycompute(Defaults.scala:253)
    - locked <0x00000000fe8dbd08> (a sbt.Defaults$)
    at sbt.Defaults$.globalIvyCore(Defaults.scala:212)
    at sbt.Defaults$.globalCore$lzycompute(Defaults.scala:165)
    - locked <0x00000000fe8dbd08> (a sbt.Defaults$)
    at sbt.Defaults$.globalCore(Defaults.scala:150)
    at sbt.Defaults$.buildCore(Defaults.scala:143)
    at sbt.internal.BuildDef.settings(BuildDef.scala:23)
    at sbt.internal.BuildDef.settings$(BuildDef.scala:23)
    at sbt.internal.BuildDef$$anon$1.settings(BuildDef.scala:34)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$buildSettings$1(Load.scala:532)
    at sbt.internal.Load$$$Lambda$1673/0x0000000019419840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$Lambda$109/0x0000000018bba840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.buildSettings(Load.scala:532)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.loaded(Load.scala:524)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI$1(Load.scala:542)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.loadAll(Load.scala:558)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.loadURI(Load.scala:488)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.load(Load.scala:467)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$1(Load.scala:243)
    at sbt.internal.Load$$$Lambda$1042/0x000000001922f840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:243)
    at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.build(GlobalPlugin.scala:59)
    at sbt.internal.GlobalPlugin$.load(GlobalPlugin.scala:64)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.loadGlobal(Load.scala:185)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultWithGlobal(Load.scala:143)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$defaultLoad$1(Load.scala:50)
    at sbt.internal.Load$$$Lambda$941/0x0000000019181840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1376)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:46)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:839)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:839)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:801)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$$Lambda$810/0x0000000019113840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:149)
    at sbt.Command$$$Lambda$661/0x000000001906e840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:144)
    at sbt.Command$$$Lambda$787/0x0000000019105440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:187)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.process$1(MainLoop.scala:193)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:229)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:142)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$644/0x000000001905a840.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.runCmd$1(State.scala:273)
    at sbt.State$StateOpsImpl$.process$extension(State.scala:277)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:142)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$643/0x000000001905a040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:142)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:133)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:111)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$636/0x000000001904e040.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:27)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:105)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:60)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:45)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:36)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:132)
    at sbt.xMain$.run(Main.scala:67)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.6/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@11.0.6/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@11.0.6/Method.java:566)
    at sbt.internal.XMainConfiguration.run(XMainConfiguration.scala:45)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:39)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:130)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:111)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:37)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:119)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.54s tid=0x0000000018331000 nid=0x438 waiting on condition  [0x000000005996e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.6/Reference.java:241)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.6/Reference.java:213)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.54s tid=0x000000001833d800 nid=0x2130 in Object.wait()  [0x0000000059e8e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000c003bfc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.6/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000c003bfc0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.6/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@11.0.6/Finalizer.java:170)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.53s tid=0x000000001834e000 nid=0x1360 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Attach Listener" #5 daemon prio=5 os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.53s tid=0x000000001834f000 nid=0x1edc waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=2308.81ms elapsed=700.53s tid=0x0000000018354000 nid=0x1ccc waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C1 CompilerThread0" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=1248.01ms elapsed=700.53s tid=0x000000001835b000 nid=0x1548 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Sweeper thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=2 cpu=31.20ms elapsed=700.53s tid=0x000000001835d800 nid=0x3098 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" #10 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.50s tid=0x0000000018506000 nid=0x19cc runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Common-Cleaner" #11 daemon prio=8 os_prio=1 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.49s tid=0x000000001850c800 nid=0x2af4 in Object.wait()  [0x000000005b9ce000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    - waiting on <no object reference available>
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.6/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000c003e4a8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@11.0.6/CleanerImpl.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.6/Thread.java:834)
    at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@11.0.6/InnocuousThread.java:134)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"classloader-cache-cleanup-0" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=698.00s tid=0x00000000626ea800 nid=0x15c8 in Object.wait()  [0x000000006374e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.6/Native Method)
    - waiting on <no object reference available>
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.6/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
    - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x00000000fdb28570> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at sbt.internal.classpath.ClassLoaderCache$CleanupThread.run(ClassLoaderCache.scala:102)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" os_prio=2 cpu=109.20ms elapsed=700.54s tid=0x000000001832d800 nid=0x1ec8 runnable  

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=2 cpu=46.80ms elapsed=700.57s tid=0x00000000002f1000 nid=0x1b3c runnable  

"GC Thread#1" os_prio=2 cpu=62.40ms elapsed=699.60s tid=0x000000005e648000 nid=0xad8 runnable  

"GC Thread#2" os_prio=2 cpu=46.80ms elapsed=699.60s tid=0x000000005e648800 nid=0x2b54 runnable  

"GC Thread#3" os_prio=2 cpu=62.40ms elapsed=699.60s tid=0x000000005e649000 nid=0x1d80 runnable  

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.57s tid=0x0000000000310000 nid=0x3a04 runnable  

"G1 Conc#0" os_prio=2 cpu=62.40ms elapsed=700.57s tid=0x0000000000311000 nid=0x332c runnable  

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=2 cpu=15.60ms elapsed=700.56s tid=0x0000000018160800 nid=0x2ea0 runnable  

"G1 Refine#1" os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=698.58s tid=0x000000005fd83800 nid=0x2abc runnable  

"G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=2 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=700.56s tid=0x000000001813a800 nid=0x3b0 runnable  
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=2 cpu=15.60ms elapsed=700.50s tid=0x0000000018507800 nid=0x274c waiting on condition  

JNI global refs: 19, weak refs: 0
```

Comment: I don't use windows that much. But could this be because of the space between Program and Files? Maybe just quote the entire value?

Comment: Actually I don't think that's the reason. When I set environment variables PATH and JAVA_HOME to point to Java 11 folder and run sbt commands from console same thing happens (and everything is OK when they point to Java 8 folder - which also have spaces in it's path between Program and Files).

Comment: When something freezes on the JVM, you should get a thread dump to see where it got stuck. Upgrading to sbt 1.3.9 might conceivably help. Running sbt with the `-debug` flag might conceivably generate more clues.

Comment: The problem is I can't run **any** sbt command (with -debug or not), they're not working at all when Java 11 is set (I just tried with Java 10 - no problem, issues begin with 11).
I can even run command like "sbt haha" - it will freeze as well and not show error.

Comment: Updated initial question with jstack log. As you see it freezes on "classloader-cache-cleanup-0" thread (if it helps).

Comment: I've encountered the same issue with sbt 1.4.9 + java 11. I see a similar stacktrace, but the difference is that `java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes` is done in a `pool-2-thread-6` and `main` thread is waiting for the lock taken in the pool thread. The result is that simple `sbt` command doesn't produce ANY output. I noticed that this issue is reproduced when I kill sbt process and the try to restart sbt. If I remove `~/.sbt/` folder the issue goes away.

Comment: With sbt `1.5.0` the issue persists, but `sbt` at least prints some output:
`[info] [launcher] getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.5.0  (this may take some time)...
:: loading settings :: url = .../ivysettings.xml
...
[info] [launcher] getting Scala 2.12.13 (for sbt)...
...
[debug] not up to date. inChanged = true, force = false
[debug] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/C:/Users/user_name/.sbt/1.0/plugins/"), "global-plugins")...`
and after `Updating ProjectRef` it's stucked

Comment: related: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5128